# ElasticSearch - Failed to execute operation for shard - NoSuchFileException

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We keep getting the NoSuchFileException on seemly random snowstorm_metrics-* indexes. Closing the offending index and re-opening it corrects the problem for a little while. Then the exception appears again usually on a different index.

The offending index is green and open but the docs.count, docs.deleted, store.size and pri.store.size are all blank. Similar to closed indexes.

[Index List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQElg.png)

The offending shards are started but several columns are blank. This only seems to happen on the offending shards all the others are populated with values.

[Shard List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Qth.png)

Following is a log file snippet:

> [2017-01-25 20:15:25,056][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.stats] [xxxxxx]
>   [indices:monitor/stats] failed to execute operation for shard
>   [[snowstorm_metrics-2017.01.10][0], node[m7W7M4eLRT2GtDjA0QgsuQ], [P],
>   v[3], s[STARTED], a[id=AoVkTo8wRXyILXdbonS_LA]]
>   ElasticsearchException[failed to refresh store stats]; nested:
>   NoSuchFileException[/opt/app/elasticsearch/data/snowstorm_logs_prod/nodes/0/indices/snowstorm_metrics-2017.01.10/0/index];
>   at
>   org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store$StoreStatsCache.refresh(Store.java:1532)

This stack is used for ELK - elastic version is 2.4.1

Comment: Did you try deleting the *indice* and recreate it again? Still the same?

Comment: We create new indexes everyday. Old indices are closed and deleted every 90 days. The problem occurs on different indices. Also closing them and re-opening the problem indices temporarily corrects the problem.